# Pass SQL to Azure virtual machine using Invoke-AzVMRunCommand

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am trying to send a script to an Azure virtual machine running SQL Server to extract some user information (see below, key connection details redacted, obviously :))

The script runs perfectly when I run it locally on the VM, outputting exactly what I need. However, if I send exactly the same script using *Invoke-AzVMRunCommand* then only the header row gets output (i.e. the SQL query returns no data).

I have put lots of unit testing in and output different strings as the script executes (by assigning the *Invoke-AzVMRunCommand* to a variable and using *.Value.Message*)  - the connection to the SQL Server instance is being made fine, but for some reason the query is returning nothing when the script is being invoked remotely instead of run locally :(

It's driving me bananas, does anyone have any ideas why it's happening??

```
# Declare temporary variables for output and array to store all the lines in
#(these will eventually be passed to the script as params from the Invoke-AzVMRunCommand
$database = "N/A (All databases)"
$svrResourceGroupName = "NFUM-303-DEV-001-UKS-RG"
$tenant = "Dev"
$service = "CRM"
$server = "DZ303NFUS008"
$outputRolesFlag = $true
$textOutputArray = @()

# Create file name for output
$Date = Get-Date
$NOW = $Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
$fileName = $("C:\Temp\PowerShellOutput\" + $server + "_SQL_User_Info_$NOW.csv")

# Create header row and add to output array
if ($outputRolesFlag) {
    $outputString = "Tenant,Service,Resource Group,SQL Server,Database,User Name,User Type,Role(s)"
}
else {
    $outputString = "Tenant,Service,Resource Group,SQL Server,Database,User Name,User Type"
}

$textOutputArray += $outputString

# Connect to database
$dbConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$dbConn.ConnectionString = "Server=tcp:<server_name>,1433;User ID=<username>;Password=<password>;Connection Timeout=30;Integrated Security=true"
try {
    $dbConn.Open()
}
catch {
    $errormessage = $error[0].Exception.Message
    $errormessage = $errormessage -split(': ')
    $errormessage = $errormessage[1]
    write-host -ForegroundColor Red $("Unable to connect to database due to error: " + $errormessage)
    break
}

# Get local groups and their roles, store in hash table
$localGroupsAndTheirRolesAndUsers = @{}
$dbCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$dbCmd.Connection = $dbConn
$dbCmd.CommandText = "select isnull(SP1.name, 'Public') as RoleName, SP2.name as GroupName from master.sys.server_role_members as SRM `
left outer join master.sys.server_principals AS SP1 on SRM.role_principal_id = SP1.principal_id `
right outer join master.sys.server_principals AS SP2 on SRM.member_principal_id = SP2.principal_id `
where sp2.type = 'G' order by GroupName" 
$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$adapter.SelectCommand = $dbCmd
$adapter.Fill($dataset) | out-null
$roles = $dataset.Tables.RoleName
$groups = $dataset.Tables.GroupName


# Assign groups to info in nested hash table
for($i=0;$i -lt $groups.Count;$i++) {
    $thisGroupsUsers = @()
    $actualGroupName = $groups[$i] -split('\\')
    $actualGroupName = $actualGroupName[1]

    # Create nested hash table
    $localGroupsAndTheirRolesAndUsers[$actualGroupName] = @{}
    
    # Assign role
    $localGroupsAndTheirRolesAndUsers[$actualGroupName]['Role'] = $roles[$i]

    # Get users, add to array, then add that to nested hash
    $thisGroupsUsersObject = Get-LocalGroupMember -name $actualGroupName
    foreach ($user in $thisGroupsUsersObject ) {
        $userName = $user.Name -split ('\\')
        $userName = $userName[1]
        $thisGroupsUsers += $userName
    }
    $localGroupsAndTheirRolesAndUsers[$actualGroupName]['Users'] = $thisGroupsUsers 
}

foreach ($group in $localGroupsAndTheirRolesAndUsers.GetEnumerator()) {
    foreach($user in $localGroupsAndTheirRolesAndUsers[$group.Key]['Users']) {
        if ($outputRolesFlag) {
            $finalUserOutputString = $($user + ",Windows," + $localGroupsAndTheirRolesAndUsers[$group.Key]['Role'])
        }
        else {
            $finalUserOutputString = $($user + ",Windows")
        }
        $outputString = $("$tenant,$service,$svrResourceGroupName,$server,$database,$finalUserOutputString") 
        $textOutputArray += $outputString
    }
}

foreach ($line in $textOutputArray) {
    $line | Out-File -Encoding ASCII -filepath $fileName -Append
}
```

The SQL statement extracted from the above script is:

```
select isnull(SP1.name, 'Public') as RoleName, SP2.name as GroupName 
from master.sys.server_role_members as SRM
left outer join master.sys.server_principals AS SP1 
on SRM.role_principal_id = SP1.principal_id
right outer join master.sys.server_principals AS SP2 
on SRM.member_principal_id = SP2.principal_id
where sp2.type = 'G' 
order by GroupName
```

Comment: _only the header row gets output (i.e. the SQL query returns no data)._ This script does have a lot in it. Can you confirm that there are zero records in the adapter after this line: `$adapter.Fill($dataset)`

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for getting back to me :-)

I am not sure how to measure the adapter directly, but I've added a measure-object to the script a bit further down:

$rolCount = $dataset.Tables.RoleName | Measure-Object
$rolCount = $rolCount.Count
$grpCount = $dataset.Tables.GroupName | measure-object
$grpCount = $grpCount.Count
write-output $rolCount
write-output $grpCount

When I run the script locally, both output 5 (which is correct), when I run it via the invoke, it's zero both times :-(

Comment: Just something along the lines of `$dataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count`?

Comment: Just a note about you connection string: you should only have one of these two: `Integrated Security=true` OR `User ID=<username>;Password=` As these are mutually exclusive authentication types

Comment: Since you seem to be happy to debug, can I suggest you remove `where sp2.type = 'G'` from the query and see what you get in both cases?

Comment: Actually I think that should be `$dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count`

Comment: Oh, that's really interesting about the connection string - I was using the Integrated Security=true because I am passing Windows credentials (mixed mode is disabled on all the SQL servers I am targeting). But, I think I may have misunderstood how that works - it just inherits the credentials of whoever is running the script, right?  In which case, I think that's possibly answered my question - the user being used to execute the code when it's being run by the Invoke-AzVMRunCommand doesn't have enough privileges to get the data... What do you think?

Comment: In any case, with your help I've just come up with a solution which is meeting my needs. I've stored the script locally on the machine, then am calling it via Windows Task Scheduler, running as myself. I then call that task using the Invoke-AzVMRunCommand, and it works fine (as it's my local Window account running the script, not Invoke-AzVMRunCommand itself).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, it's been really useful!

Comment: Generally would expect there to be any row level security on that table (filtering rows by user).. but maybe there is. Glad I could help in some way anyway

Comment: *wouldn't expect there to be row level security